# "The server was not found or was not accessible" from IIS

Tags: sql-server, iis, connection, database-connection

I have a major problem connecting to mssql server from IIS hosted application. Still same error:

```
A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
```

I have access to this database via Managment Studio. I also tested my connection string in a desktop testing app on the same machine and is working fine. Also, i had hosted older version of this app on another server (with an older version of IIS) and also worked fine.

I don't have direct access to database or firewall etc. Also, I cannot debug app in Visual Studio.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the connection string you are using? Did you give the port number as well. A screenshot of the connection page will help us provide exact solution

Comment: Double check your connection string. It sounds to me like the most likely issue the firewall not allowing traffic through.

Comment: check your connection string, you can use a .udl file in IIS computer to test connection string.

Comment: My connection string is ok. I tested it in an app - so firewall rules should be ok. Here is screenshot of error https://zapodaj.net/images/78f9c26bd01c3.jpg

Comment: I copied exact old, working app from another server (with older IIS), the same connection string. And have the same error. ;/